# Django admin view bugs

Tags: django

I got some weird bugs going on my admin view,

For example I click users:

[image]

And this what I get (The user results in the same page, not a separate page like a casual admin view):

- the rows also starched out for some reason.

[image]

Any ideas what can cause this?

Comment: You could share some code, it's difficult to figure it out without knowing the code. Probably there is some view with bad syntax or something like that. But please, "talk is cheap, show me the code"

Comment: @southernegro I will show you what ever you want, tell me what view you need. (I did not want to confuse with a lot of code.)

Comment: I recommend you to start a new project from scratch, the check the admin site and try to compare the files with yours and you could find something

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a bug. It has occured to me several times. Try connecting your computer through the internet then make a hard refresh on the page using `ctrl + f5`

I believe that should solve your issue.

It seems Django is using some external css resources but I am not very sure for this.

Comment: Maybe it a new update for Django's admin view?

Comment: if yes, please mark my answer and upvote it. Thanks

Comment: Ohh. have you tried connecting to the internet and making a hard refresh

Comment: There is one more trick I do use after encountering such issue. You could try shutting the server and running it after some minutes or hour or even shuttting down your system and then running on another port like this ```python manage.py runserver 5000```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65020639/how-to-change-the-django-3-1-3-admin-view 

Check this out. I think it is similar to what happening to you now.